# Limits problem with convolution of identically distributed random variables X and Y

Tags: probability, geometric-probability

Schaums probability and statistics book gives this problem:

Let X and Y be identically distributed independent random variables with density function:

f(t) = 1  0 \ge t \le 1,  0 otherwise

Find the density function of X + Y.  the answer given in the back of the book is

g(u) = u for 0 $\le$ t $\le$ 1, g(u) = 2-u for 1 $\le$ t $\le$ 2 , g(u)=0 otherwise. I cant see why the answer is not just:

g(u) = u for 0 $\le$ u $\le$ 2.

I dont understand the limits of the integration over v which is most likely calculated by

g(u) = $\int_0^u$ dv for 0 $\le$ v $\le$ 1, and $\int_u^2$ dv for 1 $\le$ v $\le$ 2

When drawing the graph of u on an x and y grid,  I cant figure out why the limits of v go up to 2 and why they break at u. Can anyone explain the limit

Comment: My theory is that if you put two lines with a slope of -1 on an x, y graph, one line of x + y =1 and the second with x + y =2, the integrals above would address these two areas. The reason for the break is because after the line of x + y = 1, it would be possible to exceed 2 if both x and y were say x = 1.2 and y = 1.4

Comment: I used this question to formulate this theory      http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1343220/joint-probability-density-for-independent-variables